# Nested list comprehension with enumerate build-in function

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, enumerate

I studying list comprehension and I stuck in the following code:

```
[[c for c in enumerate(r)] for r in enumerate(['a','b','c'])]
```

which returns:

```
[[(0, 0), (1, 'a')], [(0, 1), (1, 'b')], [(0, 2), (1, 'c')]]
```

However, I was expecting this:

```
[[(0,(0,'a'))],[(1,(1,'b'))],[(2,(2,'c'))]]
```

I read some articles but could not understand the prompted output. Someone can explain it to me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are enumerating *each individual element* of the outer `enumerate()`:

- You create one `enumerate()` over the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`, this produces a sequence of tuples with `(counter, letter)`.
- You then apply `enumerate()` to each of the `(counter, letter)` tuples, producing `(0, count)` and `(1, letter)` tuples *each*.

So in the end you get the following element for each of the letters in the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`:

```
[
    [(0, 0), (1, 'a')],  # enumerate((0, 'a'))
    [(0, 1), (1, 'b')],  # enumerate((1, 'b'))
    [(0, 2), (1, 'c')],  # enumerate((2, 'c'))
]
```

If you wanted to get `(counter, (counter, element))`, you need to apply `enumerate()` to the *whole output* of `enumerate()`, not to each individual tuple:

```
>>> [combo for combo in enumerate(enumerate(['a','b','c']))]
[(0, (0, 'a')), (1, (1, 'b')), (2, (2, 'c'))]
```

You could just call `list()` on `enumerate()` too:

```
>>> list(enumerate(enumerate(['a','b','c'])))
[(0, (0, 'a')), (1, (1, 'b')), (2, (2, 'c'))]
```